# How to get WGS84 axes out of astropy erfa

Tags: python, c, computational-geometry, astropy, astronomy

Astropy uses the WGS84 ellipsoid for it's `astropy.coordinates.EarthLocation.to_geodetic()` function. I'd like to make other calculations that are consistent with that function and for that, I'd like to see astropy's WGS84 representation. It seems like it comes from some C code in the _erfa submodule. Can you help me in accessing the astropy WGS84 semi-major and semi-minor axis lengths in python?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to see source code for WGS84 parameters?  They are quite well-documented. https://www.unoosa.org/pdf/icg/2012/template/WGS_84.pdf